# OpenCV python - detect and measure a gun shot on a target from a camera stream

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I would like to realize a project for a gun club. The goal is to detect and measure shots on a target and count the points. My thoughts about this projects are as follows:

1. apply a region of interest to focus onto the target
2. apply filters on the camera stream to get a sharp boundary around the black center
3. define the diameter since it is known
4. get the center of the boundary and store it as a reference point
5. detect shots and get the radial and distance in reference to the diameter and reference point and hence the value of the shot
6. show the last shots with a circle and their values on the screen

What I got so far is this:

[edge detection and center point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crcsS.jpg)

Explanation radial and distance:

[get the radial and distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ibss.jpg)

Screen with circles and values:

[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdf5D.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

# declare variables

framewidth = 1920
frameheight = 1080
RTSP_URL = 'rtsp://xxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@192.168.1.64:554/Streaming/channels/1'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
cap.set(3, framewidth)
cap.set(4, frameheight)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print('Cannot open RTSP stream')
    exit(-1)

# pseudo function

def empty(a):
    pass

# slider

cv2.namedWindow("Parameters")
cv2.resizeWindow("Parameters", 640,240)
cv2.createTrackbar("Threshold1","Parameters",16,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Threshold2","Parameters",192,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Threshold3","Parameters",243,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Threshold4","Parameters",255,255,empty)

# imagestack

def stackImages(scale,imgArray):
    rows = len(imgArray)
    cols = len(imgArray[0])
    rowsAvailable = isinstance(imgArray[0], list)
    width = imgArray[0][0].shape[1]
    height = imgArray[0][0].shape[0]
    if rowsAvailable:
        for x in range ( 0, rows):
            for y in range(0, cols):
                if imgArray[x][y].shape[:2] == imgArray[0][0].shape [:2]:
                    imgArray[x][y] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y], (0, 0), None, scale, scale)
                else:
                    imgArray[x][y] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y], (imgArray[0][0].shape[1], imgArray[0][0].shape[0]), None, scale, scale)
                if len(imgArray[x][y].shape) == 2: imgArray[x][y]= cv2.cvtColor( imgArray[x][y], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        imageBlank = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
        hor = [imageBlank]*rows
        hor_con = [imageBlank]*rows
        for x in range(0, rows):
            hor[x] = np.hstack(imgArray[x])
        ver = np.vstack(hor)
    else:
        for x in range(0, rows):
            if imgArray[x].shape[:2] == imgArray[0].shape[:2]:
                imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x], (0, 0), None, scale, scale)
            else:
                imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x], (imgArray[0].shape[1], imgArray[0].shape[0]), None,scale, scale)
            if len(imgArray[x].shape) == 2: imgArray[x] = cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        hor= np.hstack(imgArray)
        ver = hor
    return ver



def getContours(imgDil,imgContour):

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgDil, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        # compute the center of the contour
        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image

        if area > 5000:
            cv2.drawContours(imgContour, cnt, -1, (255, 0 ,255),3)
            cv2.circle(imgContour, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 0, 255), -1)
            cv2.putText(imgContour, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 255), 2)


while(True):
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgContour = img.copy()
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    threshold1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Threshold1", "Parameters")
    threshold2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Threshold2", "Parameters")
    threshold3 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Threshold3", "Parameters")
    threshold4 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Threshold4", "Parameters")
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgGray,threshold1,threshold2,1)
    imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgGray,threshold3,threshold4)
    kernel = np.ones((3,3))
    imgDil = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
    getContours(imgDil,imgContour)

    imgStack = stackImages(0.4,([img,imgGray,thresh],[imgCanny,img,imgContour]))

    cv2.imshow('Result',imgStack)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I really appreciate any suggestions on best practices and of course any help. Shall I better go for a stereo camera with depth recognition like the Oak-D, since I think the detection of a shot in the black target area could be challenging.

Comment: those are tiny thumbnails. all the _successful_ systems look at a dark screen/paper (i.e. back side) where holes let light through, which is trivial to locate. mount the camera off to the side where nobody can hit it. homography to get a frontal view of the sheet. -- don't make your life harder because that'll also make harder the lives of anyone trying to help you. -- depth cameras are a waste of time for this.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, Christoph! The targets are bright beige with a black center. I have to work with these conditions. Unfortunately it is not possible to install a light behind the targets, and it is not possible to mount the cameras at the side. It is not possible to determine the shots from behind since the targets can be attached differently, so the center can be at different locations. Those tiny thumbnails show you that I achieved #2. I don't get the point with the hard life.

Comment: light already is in front of the targets, unless your marksmen take literal shots in the dark. anyway. if you must find black holes on **well-lit** targets, I guess you should do that. it's harder because you get no contrast between holes and merely black parts of the target (contrast would have been easy), so you have to involve shape/appearance. -- can you at least mount some IR illumination behind the targets so _that_ has a chance to shine through to the front? make it bounce off some bright wall right behind. don't just point an IR light at the targets from behind.

Comment: I also thought about the solution with IR-LEDs. There are several problems with this solution. With big calibers it is really difficult to have objects behind/in front of the targets. There is always the possibility that bullet shrapnels will hit something up to 7-8 feet apart. The targets are lighted with an angle from above. Even the lights suffered small damages. The second problem is that the targets are attached to quite thick panels. IR lights at an angle won‘t shine through. That all was the reason why I was asking about the depth cam, that might detect the holes from the front.

Comment: is the room behind the targets at least bare concrete or something? that's reflective enough... but if you're saying the panels are thick and you actually get a long narrow channel through that... angles seem to matter. -- ok so scratch the backlit IR. how about frontlit IR? can you make the target paper, even the black printed parts, reflect IR, while the hole/panel material should not reflect IR?

Comment: without getting to touch and play with any of this stuff, it's hard to generate ideas or see opportunities. certainly a black hole is near indistinguishable from a black printed area of the target. there _are_ commercial solutions. I don't see why you shouldn't get one of those. if you don't, at least investigate them, see what they do differently (special targets, special lighting, special cameras, etc)

Comment: The bulletproof metal construction behind the targets are constructed in a way to redirect the bullets once they are through the target. IR lights would also be reflected away from the target.
If you have enough money, sure there are available solutions out there. Please keep in mind that there are also NPOs that do not have much money. One electronical shot measurement system for big calibers costs around 8000$ and has running costs.
The PTZ camera has IR leds. I might go in this direction and look how the paper target and the panels will reflect these lights. Anyway, thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the target after shooting and place it in front of colored light.

Buy a dirt cheap light table/tracing light box/light pad put a colored adhesive foil on top

Works great for me